# Google Chrome 81 FILE API : Size, lastmodifieddate and Blob information not updating on file content changed

Tags: google-chrome, fileapi

We are having a real time data upload application, that reads continuous streaming file. We developed this logic 2 year before.

In chrome 81, real time file upload stopped working because **file BLOB read by chrome is not getting updated** (If file data changed), it still shows old Blob. Whatever new data adding in file not showing. Further I see, **all File API properties showing old data e.g. File.lastModifiedDate, File.Size**.

In previous versions of chrome, all these properties got updated when file content got changed.

[Uploaded file details. File grown upto 1000KB, FILE API still shows old details with size 49.2KB.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzC3O.png)

I believe this is a new bug in Chrome 81 has to be addressed. Please advice if their is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this new behavior is working as intended. File objects on the web always were supposed to be immutable snapshots. Chrome in the past unfortunately had a number of exceptions where this behavior wasn't implemented properly (largely because the implementation predates the specification), and those inconsistencies were fixed in M81.

In Chrome we're also experimenting with the Native File System API (https://web.dev/native-file-system/), which explicitly does intend to support the use case of being able to read from files even after they are modified, so that might be an alternative.